# Changing image size displayed in wordpress twenty fourteen theme

Tags: images, theme-twenty-fourteen

I am using twenty fourteen theme with with the extender plugin.
I increase the content width from the extender plugin to something around 532 px.

It worked fine. But the posts containing images (even if they are wider than 474px) get displayed as 474 px wide only.

Here is a [link](http://www.ablueheart.com/football/chelsea/jose-mourinho-chronicles/2014-11-13/mourinho-vs-arsene-wenger-part1)

I didn't find any code in CSS related to this.
I found this code though in functions.php

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 474;
}
```

I tried increasing this and it worked. My question is, it is ok to change $content_width to 532px so that images become as wide as the paragraph texts. Or am I changing the wrong setting?

Comment: What is "extender plugin"?

Comment: fourteen-extended plugin for twenty fourteen theme

Comment: That doesn't quite explain it does it? :) Where is that plugin available from? Had you inquired about issue with its developers/support?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer but going by this post:http://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/why-the-content_width-wordpress-global-kinda-sucks/ I think it is ok to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably best to create a child theme and make this change in the child theme...otherwise, when a new update for the twenty fourteen them comes out, it will revert back to 474px.

Comment: I am not concerned with child theme and update issue at the moment. I want to know if this is the correct way to go i.e. changing this var value?